# Cannot retrieve specific JSON data from API call

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I am trying to use the variable `myResult` to return specific JSON data. I believe I may have written the `myResult` variable wrong and I am not querying for the correct data. The path for `'[1].show.score'`is correct and I will add in screenshots of the JSON data I am trying to call.
When I call for this data, I get returned to me this error:

[image: My error]

Here is the result of 'url'

[image: The returned JSON data from the variable 'url']

Here is my code:

```
document.querySelector('.myButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var query = document.getElementById('main').value;
  var url = fetch("http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q="+query)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
  var myResult = url[1].show.score;
  console.log(myResult);
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the data from `url` the way you are trying to access it with `url[1].show.score` because `url` is a promise that you can call `.then()` and `.catch()` on, which you already do in order to receive the data.

If you want `myResult` to use the specific data, you need to use it within the `.then()` callback

So you may have something like this in the end:

```
document.querySelector('.myButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var query = document.getElementById('main').value;
  fetch("http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q="+query)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data));
    var myResult = data[1].show.score;
    console.log(myResult);
  }
})
```